# Monorepo with multiple '@/' path aliases - works in TypeScript but not Webpack compiler

Tags: typescript, webpack, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I think this isn't possible, but worth an ask as I'm no webpack expert!

We have a monorepo with lots of different workspace packages, using typescript, built using webpack.

Each workspace has its own `tsconfig.json` and its own `webpack.config.js` to build that package.

Path aliases are declared for each like `@package-a`, `@package-b` etc.

Some packages have been imported from their own stand alone repo and declare `@` as an alias to itself.

This means we have multiple `@` aliases in different packages.

ts config

```json
"paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@package-a/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@package-b/*": ["../package-b/src/*"],
      "@package-c/*": ["../package-c/src/*"]
}
```

so in the code you can import things like

```js
import { Thing } from '@/data/models/Thing';
import { stuff, in, other, package } from '@package-c/otherThings';
```

This works however as each has a local `tsconfig.js` file that appears to work at the package level.

The problem arrises at build time.
When we have cross package dependencies - and both files are using their local alias `@` - the compiler doesn't know which to use.

Webpack has its own aliases for the build

```js
resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
      "@package-a/*": path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
      "@package-b": path.resolve(__dirname, '../package-b/src/'),
      "@package-c": path.resolve(__dirname, '../package-c/src/')
    },
  }
```

But obviously at build time, only the one webpack config is in use for that package.

Is there any way around this - or do we simply need to rename all the `@/*` references to their own package name?

Comment: What did you go for in the end? I am in the same boat and thinking of having each alias have its own name... so "@backend" "@frontend"...

Comment: same, gonna put a bounty on this one

Comment: Your current structure and alias conventions are your problem. I would use a global ts and webpack config that maybe the workspaces extend. Link to a repo?

Comment: Just went for unique package names.  Moved over to Vite now as well, may be a way to do it there?

Comment: I would use pnpm [`workspace:`](https://pnpm.io/workspaces#workspace-protocol-workspace) protocol (Yarn Berry also have this feature), this protocol will avoid downloading from npm and will use local code, this wouldn't break your build and is also supported by Lerna / [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/lerna-lite/lerna-lite) which can be use to publish releases. You should always prefer aliases scoped to your current package, not outside of its boundaries because once your package is published you'll probably get more paths problems.

Answer (score 1):

You have built a multi project project. There are many tools to hanle those projects: "Yarn Workspaces", "Npm Workspaces", and  [Lerna](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-monorepos-with-lerna)

> Lerna is a tool for managing JavaScript projects with multiple
> packages. Lerna manages monorepos, which can hold projects containing
> multiple packages within itself.

I worked with Lerna before, you can create a project with

```
 lerna init
```

this will create "packages" directory and and `lerna.json` file. you add the your webpack projects, "package1,pacakge2" into the packages directory. if you want to link packages:

```
// setting package1 as package2 dependencies 
lerna add package1 --scope=package2
```

you can check the dependencies of package2 inside its package.json. if you use Lerna, user has to have lerna cli tool installed in their machine to start the project